# Export Tier Pricing

Tags: magento-1.9, export, magmi, tierprice

I run a B2B web store, and all the products use tier pricing instead the static MSRP pricing.

When using the Import/Export, they have no field to include the tier pricing..

Is there anyway for me to efficiently export all the tier pricing for the products?

I assume MAGMI would be efficient enough to import all the products along with their tier pricing, I just need to figure out how to export them! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use native Magento 1.9 export (System -> Import/Export -> export). Tier-price related fields exported will look like these - http://screencast.com/t/p88DGX3DFQ

Since Magento itself does not allow import tier prices you have to make sure that module you chose to import them supports this format or adjust your file.